# How to edit an XML File

Tags: windows-phone-7

Howdy,
I was wondering if I was able to alter a distinct element in an XML file saved on a Windows Phone 7 device without actually having to serialize the whole file all over again.

Comment: are you trying to solve a particular problem? XML Serialization is particularly slow on WP7. Does the data have to be XML? Could you use JSON or a binary format instead?

Comment: I am working a  client/server application. The client saves an XML list of places. I implemented it in that say so that the user can use the application autonomously if he has no connection to the internet. This list holds a couple of details - one of those details is the "favorite/blacklist" status which the user should be able to set after his free will.     ---- I have just found a good workaround tho: I save this status in a distinct list in the user settings - that way I'm able to easily sync it back to the server too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in previous answers, you can't save a fragment of XML on its own without saving the whole file. If file size was a big issue, then you could split the data into separate files (perhaps alphabetically; depends on the data), so that you're only saving a smaller dataset if you make a change.

As Matt mentioned, XML serialization does not provide the best performance on WP7 devices. Kevin Marshall has a [great blog post](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2010/11/03/wp7-serialization-comparison/) detailing different serialization approaches and the performance of each. The fastest method is binary serialization, though there's nothing stopping you serializing the XML using the binary serialization approach.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no - and this has little to do with Windows Phone 7 (although I don't know whether `IsolatedStorageFileStream` on WP7 even supports seeking).

I don't know of any mainstream filesystems with high level abstractions (such as those used by Java and C#) which allow you to delete or insert data in the middle of a file.

I suppose theoretically if you were happy to pad with whitespace, or never change the length of the data you're using, you *could* just overwrite the relevant bytes - but I don't think it would be a good idea at all. Very brittle and hard to work with.

Just go for overwriting the whole file.